# Pop Up Images in Survey Dashboard

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a survey dashboard and want to be able to click on images to open in another window. That works correctly but if I click on multiple images I have many different windows open. Is there a way to make it so the window closes and the new window opens when I click on the new image?

I am able to open the images in separate new windows.

Code is shown below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).next('div').clone().dialog({width:550,height:640});"><img src="image1.jpg" width="100" height="100" align="right"/></a><div style="display:none;"><img src="image1.jpg" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px;"></img></div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).next('div').clone().dialog({width:550,height:640});"><img src="image2.jpg" width="100" height="100" align="right"/></a><div style="display:none;"><img src="image2.jpg" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px;"></img></div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).next('div').clone().dialog({width:550,height:640});"><img src="image3.jpg" width="100" height="100" align="right"/></a><div style="display:none;"><img src="image3.jpg" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px;"></img></div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).next('div').clone().dialog({width:550,height:640});"><img src="image4.jpg" width="100" height="100" align="right"/></a><div style="display:none;"><img src="image4.jpg" style="max-width:500px;max-height:500px;"></img></div>
```

Would like one image window to close when you open the new image or have the new image replace the old one.

Comment: Can you put this in a [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/)? [This](http://javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml) could be of help as well.

Answer (score 1):

No. After creating a new window you can't close it when you click on another image. That is not possible.

Instead of creating a new window, you can show the image in the same window.

Please try the following approaches.

1. Modal Images
   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp
2. Light Box
   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp
3. Image Gallery
   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp

Answer (score 0):

All dialog have "ui-dialog-content" class, so select that and close them before opening new dialog.

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/